Reheating a rice dish in a slowcooker
I am (not professionally) trying to provide a luncheon for 8 people at a location that has no cooking facilities. The dish is a rice pilaf. Normally, I would set out a little buffet with trays nested in a water bath and beneath it one of those tins of chafing fuel. Unfortunately, the location is small and poorly ventilated, so I believe the fumes would be unpleasant.
Can I just dump the rice into a slow cooker to reheat it? For how long should I plan to reheat the rice if there are about 8 portions? (about 3 cups of cooked rice, along with meat and veg).

How far in advance are you cooking the food?  When I bring fried rice to pot lucks or similar, I  put my rice cooker on warm then load it with the freshly fried rice (cooked in batches), so it only has to maintain heat, not reheat it.

@Joe it would have been a 4 hours' lead time. Interestingly thought to "hold" the dish at temperature. There's a possibility that cooking right before leaving, (so temp is ~350 when pulled out of oven), then putting to stay hot in the plate could avoid the danger zone without necessarily drying it out.

In general, slow cookers are poor for reheating, especially large quantities. They simply don't deliver heat fast enough to get back up to a safe temperature quickly. For similar reasons, slow cooker recipes usually call for adding at least some ingredients (such as stock) hot.
I certainly wouldn't risk it for a group - even preheating for longer than normal and adding a little boiling water (to stop it sticking to the bottom and provide some steam to distribute heat) it's going to take at least an hour, and you've already used up a lot of safety margin during cooling. Rice is a high risk food.
They can be very good for serving from, if you need to serve over a long period. But some drying out is to be expected with something like a pilaf that's fairly dry to start with.
An electric hotplate that's suitable for cooking would be far more suitable for reheating
